# Como guardar un diccionario en la base de datos django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hice una base de datos con models y ahora con un formulario (Modelform) obtengo una parte de los datos que quiero guardar, dentro de views genere los otros datos que completan la información para guardar en la base de datos

Aqui obtengo las respuestas del form:

```
respuestasformulario=miformulario(request.POST,request.FILES)
```

Aqui guardo en un diccionario las respues limpias:

```
respuestaslimpias=respuestasformulario.cleaned_data
....
```

Despues agrego al diccionario la información necesaria para la base de datos (Usando if, lower, practicamente otra limpieza)

Obtengo respuestas limpias pero con todos los campos necesarios para guardar en la base de datos, el problema es el siguiente:

Si pongo `respuestaslimpias.save()`  no se guarda en la DB ya que necesito que sea este `respuestasformulario.save()`

Entonces, como puedo hacer que la información regrese a `respuestasformulario()` o como guardo el diccionario en `respuestaslimpias()`

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento. No implores ayuda: en lugar de ello, pulsa en [edit] y mejora tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente pude!!! Por si alguien le sirve se hace de la siguiente forma mi model en la base de datos es "servicio" y en mi base un dato necesatio es el titulo1 y titulo2
primero dentro del mismo view donde tenia el problema pongo lo siguiente

```
datosfaltantes=servicio(titulo1='DATO A GUARDAR',titulo2='OTRO DATO A GUARDAR')
```

Lo siguiente yo lo veo como crear una nueva respuesta de mi formulario pero yo agregando los datos faltantes de la siguiente forma

```
form=respuestasformulario(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=datosfaltantes)

form.save()
```

Y listo ya tendrias agregados los datos del formulario mas los datos faltantes en tu base de datos